# Add Div using JQUERY-Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

We're trying to add the modal-body to the email.  Does anyone know what we're doing wrong?  We included it here at the top, var content = $("#modal-body").text("");  AND $("#modal-body").text("");
Then we put the div class="modal-body

```
 eventClick: function(event) {
  console.log(event)
    // alert(event.start.format('MMMM Do YYYY'))
  var start = event.start.format('MMMM Do YYYY'),
    end = event.end.format('MMMM Do YYYY'),
    html = '<p>Starts: ' + start + '<p>';
  html += '<p>Ends: ' + end + '<p>';
  var modal = $("#modal");
  modal.find(".modal-title").html(event.title);
  modal.find('.modal-body').html(html)
  modal.modal();
    }
});
});
 });//]]> 


jQuery(function($)  
{
$("#contact_form").submit(function()
{
    var content = $("#modal-body").text("");
    var email = $("#email").val(); // get email field value
    var name = $("#name").val(); // get name field value
    var msg = $("#msg").val(); // get message field value
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json",
        data: {
            'key': 'hlg_vG6ftPebBiLnrNSCVA',
            'message': {
                'from_email': "email@email.com",
                'from_name': "name",
                'headers': {
                    'Reply-To': "email@email.com"
                },
                'subject': 'Confirmation - Sign Up',
                'text':  content, 
                'to': [
                {
                    'email': email,
                    'name': name,
                    'type': 'to'
                }]

            }
        }
    })
    .done(function(response) {
        alert('You have been signed up. Thank you!'); // show success message
        $("#name").val(''); // reset field after successful submission
        $("#email").val(''); // reset field after successful submission
        $("#msg").val(''); // reset field after successful submission
        $("#modal-body").text("");
    })
```

Comment: $('#modal-body').text("") sets the value to an empty string just in case... Basically instead of getting the text you are erasing it.

Comment: If you can, post a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with your code? Also, do you have any clue what part is failing? i.e. are there error messages in the console?

Comment: @Lanie909 Thanks for the jsfiddle. Unfortunately it doesn't load all your CSS/JS so the modal and calendar don't display. The email and name vars are getting set right, but I cannot check the modal. If you run your app locally and add lines such as "console.log("content: " + content + " msg: " + msg + "");" do you get anything in the console? (Do you use Chrome/Firefox?) In chrome you can pull up console with Control + Shift+ i and try your jquery there ($("#modal-body").text();) and see if it picks anything up.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
var content = $("#modal-body").text("");
```

Is erasing the content instead of reading it. Try to change it with:

```
var content = $("#modal-body").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your jsfiddle, you have a block like so:

```
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function() {
...
```

First of all that will not work.  The dom event fires for ready before it fires load.  You can safely remove either `$(window).load` or the `$(document).ready`.
`$(window).load` triggers when all images and scripts/styles have loaded.  `$(document).ready` triggers as soon as the DOM has loaded.

Second you definitely need to change the line from:

```
var content = $("#modal-body").text("");
```

which sets the value to an empty string, so instead of getting the text you are erasing it.  Instead you want:

```
var content = $("#modal-body").text();
```

Gets the value and stores it in content.